# One-sided test for AUC (area under the curve for ROC)

Tags: roc, auc

I am trying to determine the power of testing the AUC of a diagnostic test with continuous score against a one-sided alternative. I was thinking I could just use the confidence intervals produced by `ci.auc` from the R package `pROC`. By checking whether the lower limit of the confidence interval is larger than my value hypothesized under H0, the test should have 2.5% type I error rate.

However, my simulation does not really adhere to these principles. Although true coverage rate is approximately 95% for AUC values smaller than around 0.9, the type I error rate for the one-sided test is in many cases much larger than the anticipated 2.5%. In fact, it seems to be much closer to the type I error rate for the *two-sided test*, i.e. 5%.

Code follows. I am sorry for the quite naive code. I hope, it's comprehensible.

```
library(pROC)

auc_non_inferior <- function(n1, n2, auc_h1, auc_noninferior, nsim){
  estimated.auc <- c(); lower.limit <- c(); upper.limit <- c()
  for(i in 1:nsim){
    # the following line is a command that guarantees that the means of the normal distribution are such that at average the specified AUC is the result (if the other normal distribution has mean=0 and both have sd=1)
    cut.off <- seq(0,1,by=0.0001)[which(abs(pnorm(qnorm(seq(0,1,by=0.0001))/sqrt(2)) - auc_h1)^2 == min((abs(pnorm(qnorm(seq(0,1,by=0.0001))/sqrt(2)) - auc_h1)^2)))]
    # I bet there is a much more elegant way to do this. But it works.
    
    x1 <- rnorm(n=n1, mean=0, sd=1) # true negatives
    x2 <- rnorm(n=n2, mean=qnorm(cut.off), sd=1) # true positives (with mean)
    
    pos <- rep(0, length(x1))
    neg <- rep(1, length(x2))
    
    roc.fit <- roc(c(pos,neg), c(x1,x2), quiet = T) # calculate AUC via pROC package
    estimated.auc[i] <- ci.auc(roc.fit)[2] # calculates DeLong confidence interval with [2] being the estimated AUC
    lower.limit[i] <- ci.auc(roc.fit)[1] # and [1] being the lower limit of the 95% confidence interval
    upper.limit[i] <- ci.auc(roc.fit)[3] # and [3] being the upper limit of the 95% confidence interval
  }
  power <- sum((lower.limit)>auc_noninferior)/length(lower.limit)
  true.value.in.CI <- (lower.limit < auc_h1) & (auc_h1 < upper.limit) 
  return(list("Mean AUC"=mean(estimated.auc), "Power of Non-Inferiority test"=power, "coverage"=sum(true.value.in.CI)/nsim))
}
```

To give an example result of the function:

```
set.seed(16)
auc_non_inferior(n1=100, n2=100, auc_h1=0.75, auc_noninferior=0.75, nsim=1e4)
> $`Mean AUC`
> [1] 0.7495468 # this is as expected, since auc_h1=0.75

> $`Power of Non-Inferiority test` 
> [1] 0.0381 # here I expected 0.025

> $coverage
> [1] 0.9437 # close to expected 95%
```

Are the confidence intervals for the AUC not meant to equally spend type I error probability on both sides, i.e. values being larger and smaller? If so, why? And how can I do a one-sided test for AUC then? Or is something else wrong with this simulation?